# Invariant measure of Euler-Maruyama Discretisation of an Ito diffusion

Tags: probability, numerical-methods, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus

Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a diffusion process with dynamics governed by the stochastic differential equation
\begin{equation}
dX_t = b(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t, ~~ X_0 = x_0,
\end{equation}
where $b,\sigma$ are Lipschitz and $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard $d$-dimensional Wiener process.  Assume $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ possesses a unique invariant probability measure $\mu(\cdot)$.

The Euler-Maruayama approximation of this SDE with step size $h$ is a Markov chain defined recursively as $Y_0 = x_0$, and for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$
\begin{equation}
Y_{(n+1)h}|Y_{nh} = Y_{nh} + b(Y_{nh})h + \sqrt{h}\sigma(Y_{nh})\varepsilon, ~~ \varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_{d \times d}).
\end{equation}

I can see that under certain conditions $\{Y_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ will also possess a unique invariant probability measure, $\mu^h(\cdot)$.  I've seen certain results discussing how the ergodicity properties of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $\{Y_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ can differ (e.g. scenarios in which the first can be exponentially ergodic but the second transient, see: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1178291835).

What I've been unable to find are results discussing how $\mu^h(\cdot)$ and $\mu(\cdot)$ differ.  Can we make some statement about how 'close' the two measures are, in total variation
\begin{equation}
\| \mu^h(\cdot) - \mu(\cdot) \|_{TV}
\end{equation}
or some other appropriate distance.  And can we say anything about the distance
\begin{equation}
\|\mathbb{E}_{\mu^h}f - \mathbb{E}_{\mu}f\|
\end{equation}
for some suitable class of functions $f$, assuming both processes are defined on the same space which has norm $\|\cdot\|$?  I've searched around online a bit, the closest I've come is here http://www.newton.ac.uk/preprints/NI03065.pdf, where the result is alluded to, which makes me think it might be fairly well known.  So if anyone could point me in the right direction or explain why it's obvious then that would be great, thanks!

Also asked on Math overflow here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163443/invariant-measure-of-euler-maruyama-discretisation-of-an-ito-diffusion/163489?noredirect=1#163489

Comment: I have been thinking about a similar [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239665/transition-semigroup-of-ito-diffusion-on-l2-mathbbr). May I know whether you have any reference about when the Ito diffusion $X_t$ has a sub-invariant probability measure?

Comment: I don't have a concrete reference, but certainly related to strongly continuous semigroups you may be able to find something in 'Analysis and geometry of Markov diffusion operators' by Bakry, Gentil & Ledoux.

Comment: @John I know that this is an old comment, but if you happen to have at hand any reference on when an Ito diffusion has sub-invariant prob. measure I would be very much interested.

Comment: @don'tstopthebit Sorry I don't have any reference on the sub-invariant prob. measure at hand.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good papers on studying convergence and stationary distributions of discretizations.

Mattingly et. al. (2002) proves a Lyapunov and minorization condition required for geometric ergodicity of Markov chains, and also provided a (loose) result on how close the stationary distributions are. 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414902001503

Mattingly et. al. (2010) essentially studies a Stein's method like technique, where the authors provide a weak error bound for the stationary distribution of the Euler method. 
https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.4450

Debussche and Faou (2011) constructed an approximate stationary distribution for the Euler method using weak backward error analysis, if you want to prove properties about the Euler method. 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0489

The last two papers were studying SDEs on a torus to avoid technical details that $\mathbb{R}^d$ brings, but these results have been extended by later papers.

Comment: You might want to include in this list the Durmus et al. series of papers and the Rakhlin-Raginsky-Telgarsky one. Arent these also of the same category as your 3 references?