# can two Markov kernels be close in total variation and differ in their ergodicity properties?

Tags: functional-analysis, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

This is a question inspired by a [recent MCMC paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03387) and linked to an [earlier question of Sam Livingstone](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/751991/14893) that did not get any answer.

Given two Markov kernels $\mathfrak{K}$ and $\mathfrak{H}$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\vert\vert\mathfrak{K}(x,\cdot)-\mathfrak{H}(x,\cdot)\vert\vert_\text{TV}<\epsilon$$
where $$\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert_\text{TV}$$ denotes the total variation norm, is it possible that the Markov kernel $\mathfrak{K}$ is ergodic while the Markov kernel $\mathfrak{H}$ is not (i.e., is null recurrent or even transient)?

Comment: Rereading this post almost two years later, I feel the question has not really been addressed, namely: *Given some ergodic Markov kernel $K$, does there exist some positive $\varepsilon$ such that, for every Markov kernel $H$, if $\sup\limits_{x\in\mathcal X}\|H(x,\cdot)-K(x,\cdot)\|_{\mathrm{TV}}\leqslant\varepsilon$ then $H$ is ergodic as well?* // The answer below exhibits ergodic kernels $K$ as close to some specific non ergodic kernel $H$ as desired (a task which, in view of the general fact that the interior of the set of non ergodic kernels is empty, is comparatively trivial).

Comment: Oh, and at least for finite Markov chains, the answer to the question stated in my previous comment is "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two Markov kernels on the finite state space $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, expressed as stochastic matrices:
$$
K_\epsilon=\left[\matrix{ 0&1-\epsilon&\epsilon&0&0\cr
1-\epsilon&\epsilon&0&0&0\cr
\epsilon&0&1-2\epsilon&\epsilon&0\cr
0&0&\epsilon&0&1-\epsilon\cr
0&0&0&1-\epsilon&\epsilon\cr}
\right]
$$
and
$$
H=\left[\matrix{ 0&1&0&0&0\cr
1&0&0&0&0\cr
0&0&1&0&0\cr
0&0&0&0&1\cr
0&0&0&1&0\cr}
\right].
$$
The total variation distance between $K_\epsilon$ and $H$ is $2\epsilon$, and $K_\epsilon$ is ergodic (if $\epsilon>0$) while $H$ is not.

Comment: I was wondering at a case when irreducibility is not the issue but positive recurrence is.

Comment: How about the simple random walk on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ with $p_{k.k+1}=p$, $p_{k,k-1}=1-p$ (for $k=1,2,\ldots$) and $p_{0,1}=1-p_{0,0}=p$? (Call the corresponding transition matrix $K_p$.) This random walk is positive recurrent if $0<p<1/2$, null recurrent if $p=1/2$. The total variation distance between the $K_p$ and $K_{1/2}$ is $p-1/2$ for $0<p<1/2$.

Comment: This makes a perfect example for my argument, thank you.